# How do I permanently uninstall a virtual CD-Drive containing Tails?

Tags: tails

So for a class assignment we had to install tails on our computer. It seems I've went some round about way and managed to install it as a virtual-cd drive.

Only thing is I can't remove it. I've tried going to device manager and uninstalling it. It disappears, but then reappears back with the other disk drives in My Computer once I've restarted the computer.

Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: Is there anything in program/features in the control panel that sound like something used for virtual-drives? Pretty jealous that you're using tails in a classroom environment.

Comment: Windows 10

Under device manager, I can uninstall it, but it always comes back when I restart the PC.